# Dynamic size array of templated parameters passed to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I have been trying to find a way of how to make a function that can receive any kind of variables and a dynamic amount of them to a function.

The reason for that functionality, is because I'm wrapping the std::function and I want to call the std::function I hold but with a dynamic values that I hold.

Example of class:

```
class Task {

     public:
         //C'tor init etc...
         Task(Dynamic array of values to be saved in a vector) { 
               //Saving the variables in a vector code piece
         }
         void execute() {
               myFuncPtr(vectorValues);
         }

     private:
        std::function<void(templated array of value types) myFuncPtr;
        std::vector<wrapper for templated values> vectorValues;
};


//Example of wanted use:
void main() {

    int counter = 0;
    std::string name("Some name...");
    std::function<int(void)> funcPtr(some function...);
    ITask task<int,std::string, std::function<int(void)>>(counter, name, funcPtr);
    task.execute();

}
```

Is there any way to implement this logic?

Thanks heads up :)

Comment: you should look for variadic templates

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say from your question but, looks like you want to bind the arguments ahead of time into a generic Task object.

You could just use `std::bind()` which will give you a type erased `std::function` object back, with your arguments bound in or use a capturing lambda, ie,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

void someFunc(const std::string& name, int value)
{
   std::cout << name << " " << value << std::endl;  
}

int main() {

  int count =0;
  std::string name("Some name...");


  std::function<void()> task = std::bind(&someFunc,name,count );

  //alternative without bind is to wrap it in a capturing lambda
  std::function<void()> task2 = [=](){ someFunc(name,count); };

  task();
  task2();
  return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/ClbJpU)

Or if you want to use your example Task class, something like this would work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Task {

     public:
         template <typename Func, typename... Args>
         Task(Func&& f,Args&&... args) :
            func_([=]()
             { f(args...); })
        {}

        void execute() 
        {
            func_();
        }

     private:
        std::function<void()> func_;

};

void someFunc(const std::string& name,int count)
{
   std::cout << name << " " << count;

}
//Example of wanted use:
int main() {

    int counter = 0;
    std::string name("Some name...");

    Task task(&someFunc,name,counter);
    task.execute();

    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/01eguf)